# Inconsistent footnote size in converting LaTeX to OpenOffice.org

Tags: footnotes, fontsize, conversion, tex4ht

When a LaTeX document containing 2 footnotes — footnote #1 is plain ASCII, but footnote #2 has diacritics or other extended characters — is converted to `odt` (OpenDocument Format), the number in footnote #1 is smaller than the number in footnote #2.

- Do you get the same output?
- How can I make the numbers be of the same size?

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
First sentence.\footnote{First footnote.}
Second sentence.\footnote{S{\' e}cond footnote.}
\end{document}
```

This is the output from `pdftex`:

[image: Imgur]

And this is the output from `$ mk4ht oolatex`

[image: output]

TeX Live (2012), mk4ht (v1.1), OpenOffice.org (3.4.1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like openoffice bug to me. If you unzip the `odt` file and open `content.xml` file, you can see:

```
...
<text:note text:note-class="footnote" text:id="fn1x0"><text:note-citation>1</text:note-citation><text:note-body> <text:p text:style-name="Footnote"><text:span text:style-name="ecrm-0800">First footnote.</text:span></text:p></text:note-body></text:note>
....
<text:note text:note-class="footnote" text:id="fn2x0"><text:note-citation>2</text:note-citation><text:note-body> <text:p text:style-name="Footnote"><text:span text:style-name="ecrm-0800">S</text:span><text:span text:style-name="ecrm-0800">&#xE9;</text:span><text:span text:style-name="ecrm-0800">cond footnote.</text:span></text:p></text:note-body></text:note>
...
```

Only difference between the two footnotes is that there are some extra `<text:span ...>` elements in the second footnote. This is caused by how `tex4ht` handles accented letters. It seems that openoffice chooses footnote mark size according do biggest element in footnote text, but in this case all elements are the same size, so there should be no reason why the footnote mark is bigger.

To get rid of these `<text:span>` elements, we must redefine footnote handling in `oolatex`. Create dummy package `myfootnote.sty` and use this package in your preamble. This file can be empty, it's purpose is only to call file `myfootnote.4ht` when running with `tex4ht`. Now contents of `myfootnote.4ht`:

```
\:CheckOption{ooffice}\if:Option
\Configure{automatic-styles}
   {\csname a:footnote-style\endcsname}
\NewConfigure{footnote-style}{1}
\Configure{footnote-style}{%
<style:style style:name="Footnote-text" style:family="text">
<style:text-properties fo:font-size="10.0pt" />
</style:style>
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\Configure{footnotetext}
   {\Tag{fn\FNnum x\minipageNum
-tx}{}%
    \ifTag{fn\FNnum x\minipageNum
}
   {\expandafter\ifx\csname (fn\FNnum x\minipageNum
)\endcsname\def
       \:warning{Multiple footnote texts for mark \FNnum}%
    \fi
   } {}%
%
    \SaveEndP \NoFonts  \let\@textsuperscript\hbox
    \HCode{<\text:footnote\Hnewline\text:note:class
             text:id="}fn\FNnum x\minipageNum
%
               \HCode{"><\text:footnote-citation>}%
    \IgnorePar \special{t4ht@(}%
   }
   {\EndNoFonts \RecallEndP
    \HCode{</\text:footnote-citation><\text:footnote-body>
    <text:p\Hnewline text:style-name="Footnote"><text:span text:style-name="Footnote-text">}\NoFonts%
    \SaveHtmlPar \Configure{HtmlPar}
   {\EndP \HCode{<text:p text:style-name="Footnote"><text:span text:style-name="Footnote-text">}}
   {\EndP \HCode{<text:p text:style-name="Footnote"><text:span text:style-name="Footnote-text">}}
   {\HCode{</text:span></text:p>}}
   {\HCode{</text:span></text:p>}}%
\ShowPar \special{t4ht@)}%
   }
   {\RecallHtmlPar \EndNoFonts\HCode{</text:span></text:p></\text:footnote-body></\text:footnote>}%
   \expandafter\global\expandafter
   \let\csname (fn\FNnum x\minipageNum
)\endcsname\def
%
   }
}
\fi
```

with `\:CheckOption{ooffice}` we ensure that this code is included only if document is running with `oolatex`, not with `htlatex`. Then we create openoffice style `Footnote-text`, which is included with `\Configure{automatic-styles}` into main document. Then there is `\Configure{footnotetext}`. We must include it in `\AtBeginDocument`, otherwise it is replaced with default values. Contents are copied from the file `ooffice.4ht`, we only added some tags and `\NoFonts` and `\EndNoFonts` macros, which suppresses creation of `<text:span>` elements for characters with diacritics.