# How to write tex4ht source files

Tags: tex4ht, learning, open-office

How can I learn how to edit `4ht` files? What should I read?

I want to fix a number of issues in  `ooffice.4ht` ([inconsistent footnote size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88498), style names which mismatch names used by LibreOffice, dangling space at the end of sentences, etc.)

I've read the chapter on `tex4ht` in the *LaTeX Web Companion*, but I'm still unable to read, let alone modify, it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Open document format` is big and ugly, so `ooffice.4ht` is also big and ugly. If you want to better understand, what is going on, you must understand some basics, which are described in resources posted in your post.

`ooffice.4ht` also add some custom macros, useful for dealing with styles. There are two types of styles used here. One are defined in file with text content, an they are configured like in the [answer about inconsistent footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88498):

```
\Configure{automatic-styles}
   {\csname a:footnote-style\endcsname}
\NewConfigure{footnote-style}{1}
\Configure{footnote-style}{%
<style:style style:name="Footnote-text" style:family="text">
<style:text-properties fo:font-size="10.0pt" />
</style:style>
}
```

With `\NewConfigure{footnote-style}{1}` you are declaring new configuration `footnote-style`, with one parameter. With `\Configure{footnote-style}` you declare the style and
`\Configure{automatic-styles}` is inserting call to the declared configuration `footnote-style`. You must use internal name `a:footnote-style`, this is created automaticaly by `NewConfigure`.

Other style macros are `\NewConfigureOO` and `\ConfigureOO`:

```
\NewConfigureOO{textul}
\ConfigureOO{textul}{<style:style style:name="textul" style:family="text">
    <style:text-properties style:text-underline-style="solid"
                           style:text-underline-width="auto"
                           style:text-underline-color="font-color"
    />
</style:style>
}
```

These configurations go to the `settings.xml` file. I don't know what is the key about what styles belongs to `styles.xml` and which to the `content.xml`, you must find that in `odf` documentation.

Other parts of that file deals with command redefinitions for inserting configurable hooks and providing `xml` configurations with these hooks.

Answer (score 5):

#### `tex4ht`:

1. [documentation](http://svn.gnu.org.ua/viewvc/tex4ht/trunk/doc/cvr/) in source repository.
2. more on [configuration](http://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn11.html) at `tug.org`
3. Michel Goossens, Sebastian Rahtz et al. *The LaTeX Web Companion*. Addison
   Wesley, 1999, pp. 169-194,404-415.

#### `ooffice.4ht`:

1. Maarten Wisse (2002) “[Hacking TeX4ht for XML Output: The Road toward a TeX 
   to Word Convertor](http://www.ntg.nl/maps/28/09.pdf)”, MAPS 28, 2002, pp. 28-35.